# React upload file to laravel server error

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, redux

well I am trying to upload image  file to laravel server with react but this seems not to work. I tried it with blade template and its working. Now with react it not detecting the `file`, also i am using `redux` with `axios` for `api` call, here is my codes:

create-post action:

```
 export function add_post(data) {
    return function(dispatch) {
      const formdata = new FormData();
      formdata .append("file",data.file);
      formdata .file = formdata;
      return axios.post("/posts",data,{
       headers:{
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
       }
      })
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data);
        dispatch(fetch_posts_data());
        dispatch(post_notify({
          message:"Post Created!",
          type:"success"
        }))
             setTimeout(function(){
            dispatch(close_notification())
          },2000)
      })
      .catch((err)=>console.log(err));
    };
  }
```

createPost component:

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Formik,Field} from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import 'react-summernote/dist/react-summernote.css';
import {add_post} from "../store/thunks"
import {useDispatch} from "react-redux"

const FormSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    title: Yup.string()
      .min(2, 'Too Short!')
      .required('Required'),
    body: Yup.string()
      .min(10, 'Too Short!')
      .required('Required'),
  });

const CreatePost = (props)=>{
  const dispatch  = useDispatch();
  const [file,setfile] = useState(null)
  const addimage = e=>{
    setfile(e.target.files[0])
  }
    return(
        <Formik
        validationSchema={FormSchema}
               initialValues={{
        title: '',
        body: ''
      }}
        onSubmit={values => {
         dispatch(add_post({...values,file:file}));
         props.history.push("/")
      }}
      render = {({ handleSubmit}) => (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="form-group mt-2">
        <Field name="title" placeholder="title" type={'text'} component={customInputForm}/>
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="#body">body</label>
        <Field name="body"  component={customTextarea}/>
      </div>
      <div className="form-group mt-2">
          <label >Image</label>
          <input type="file"
            className="form-control" id='file' accept="image/*" onChange={addimage}/>
        </div> 
    <div  className="d-flex">
    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary  ml-auto">Add</button>
    </div>
                  </form>   )
                    }/>

    )
}
export const customInputForm = ({field, form: {touched, errors}, ...props}) => (
  <>
   <label>{props.name}</label>
      <input
      className={`form-control ${!!(touched[field.name] && errors[field.name])?"is-invalid":""}`}
          {...field}
          {...props} />
      {touched[field.name] && errors[field.name] && <div className="invalid-feedback d-block">{errors[field.name]}</div>}
      </>
);
export const customTextarea = ({field, form: {touched, errors}, ...props}) => (
  <>
     <label>{props.name}</label>
      <textarea  style={{height:300}}
      className={`form-control ${!!(touched[field.name] && errors[field.name])?"is-invalid":""}`}
      name={props.name}
          {...field}
          {...props} ></textarea>
      {touched[field.name] && errors[field.name] && <div className="invalid-feedback d-block">{errors[field.name]}</div>}
      </>
);
```

and for server controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if($request->hasFile("file")){
        $filenameWithExt = $request->file("file")->getClientOriginalName();
        $filename= pathinfo($filenameWithExt,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $extension = $request->file("file")->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileNameToStore = $filename."_".time().".".$extension;
        $path= $request->file("file")->storeAs("public/images",$fileNameToStore);
    }
    else{
        $fileNameToStore = "no-image.svg";
        $path="public/images/no-image.svg";
    };
    $post = new Post;
    $post->title= $request->title;
    $post->body= $request->body;
    $post->image_name= $fileNameToStore;
    $post->image_path = $path;
    $post->save();

}
```

well the server is always setting `$fileNameToStore` to `no-image.svg`. this mean file is not detected i have tried a lot of suggested solution but nothing work. please hope you got a solution for this and thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 const formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append("file",data.file);
  return axios.post("/posts",formdata,{
   headers:{
    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
   }
  })
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I need to send other inforamtions not only formdata!

Comment: formData.append('data', data)

Comment: solved  `formdata.append("file",data.file);
      formdata.append("title",data.title);
      formdata.append("body",data.body);
      return axios.post("/posts",formdata,{
       headers:{
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
       }
      })` thank you a lot!